# Understanding why smaller executors fail and larger succeeds in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a job that parses approximate a terabyte of json formatted data split in 20 mb files (this is because each minute gets a 1gb dataset essentially).

The job parses, filters, and transforms this data and writes it back out to another path.  However, whether it runs depends on the spark configuration.

The cluster consists of 46 nodes with 96 cores and 768 gb memory per node.  The driver has the same specs.

I submit the job in standalone mode and:

1. Using 22g and 3 cores per executor, the job fails due to gc and OOM

```
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco                                              
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value                              
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError19/04/13 01:35:32 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.0.118.151:34014      
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded                                                                          
        at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Base$DigestIntegrity.getHMAC(DigestMD5Base.java:1060)                           
        at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Base$DigestPrivacy.unwrap(DigestMD5Base.java:1470)                             
        at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Base.unwrap(DigestMD5Base.java:213)                                           
        at org.apache.spark.network.sasl.SparkSaslServer.unwrap(SparkSaslServer.java:150)                                        
        at org.apache.spark.network.sasl.SaslEncryption$DecryptionHandler.decode(SaslEncryption.java:126)                       
        at org.apache.spark.network.sasl.SaslEncryption$DecryptionHandler.decode(SaslEncryption.java:101)                        
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)                          
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)              
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)             
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)                
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)                       
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)              
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)              
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)                
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)                     
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)             
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)             
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)                              
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)                      
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)                                                              
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)                                 
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)                                                                                              
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)                                                                                     
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)                         
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)             
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                                                                                 
: An error occurred while calling o54.json.                                                                                                                                                                                              
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

2. Using 120g and 15 cores per executor, the job succeeds.

Why would the job fail on the smaller memory/core setup?

Notes:
There is an explode operation that possibly may be related as well. Edit: Unrelated.  Tested the code, did a simple spark.read.json().count().show() and it gc'd and OOM'd.

My current pet theory at the moment is the the large number of small files results in high shuffle overhead.  Is this what's going on and is there a way around this (outside of re-aggregating the files separately)?

Code as requested:
Launcher

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://0.0.0.0:7077 \
--conf "spark.executor.memory=90g" \
--conf "spark.executor.cores=12" \
--conf 'spark.default.parallelism=7200' \
--conf 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=380' \
--conf "spark.network.timeout=900s" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$LIB_JARS" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=$LIB_JARS" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \
launcher.py
```

Code

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('Rewrites by Frequency') \
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.read.json("s3://path/to/file").count()
```

Comment: Could you update on how many executor launched in both the case ?

Comment: Hi, my understanding that spark nowadays computes number of executors based off of cores/memory.  In 3 core case, that would mean a max of 1472 executors.  In 15 core case, max of 276 executors.

Comment: These kinds of errors tend to come up when your partitioning is sub-optimal (i.e. you have some partitions which can't fit into one executor's memory). If you post some code, we might be able to guide you further. Furthermore, JSON is quite an inefficient data format, depending on what your data looks like you might get better performance using Parquet.